# Angular2 routing redirects for unknown reason

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have a problem with my angular2 routing that makes it so that all child routes changes the URL to root.

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: TransferComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'transfer', component: TransferComponent },
    { path: 'converter', component: ConverterComponent },
    { path: 'beneficiary', component: PortalTransfersComponent },
    {
        path: 'portal', component: PortalComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'transfers', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'profile', component: PortalProfileComponent },
            { path: 'transfers', component: PortalTransfersComponent }
        ]
    },

    { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
        TooltipModule.forRoot(),
        ButtonsModule.forRoot(),
        TabsModule.forRoot(),
        ModalModule.forRoot()
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    providers: []
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Those are my routes, and all of them sort of works. i.e. when I go to `/portal/transfers` the correct component is shown and in that regard it is working. However if I look in the address bar of the browser it doesn't show `/portal/transfers` it shows web root.

This would be fine if it wasn't for the fact that if I refresh the page I don't stay on the `PortalTransfersComponent`, instead I get the `TransferComponent`

Does anyone know what could cause this?

could be interesting to note that if I by following links go to `/beneficiary` and then `/portal/transfers` it changes the URL to `/beneficiary` instead of root

Turns out the error was not directly related to the route file.
There was some sort of dirty fix on the PortalComponent, that resulted in a missing `<router-outlet>` tag.
Adding it made everything work as expected.

Comment: It does load /transfer because that's what you have in your url. But I am trying to understand why you would redirect if it's not what you wish

Comment: Yeah, I have /transfer in my URL, but it is not what I entered. The thing is that when I point my browser to /portal/transfers, it changes the URL to /transfer while still displaying the PortalTransfersComponent. What I would like to happen is that when I go to /portal/transfers the URL stays on /portal/transfers and it displays the component PortalTransfersComponent

Comment: In this case, remove { path: '', redirectTo: 'transfer', pathMatch: 'full' }. For what purpose do you have it?

Comment: removed it and I have the same problem. only difference is that I now the the NotFoundComponent when I navigate to web root

Comment: So add    { path: '', component: TransferComponent }  at the first line instead of what you removed. But your link /portal/transfers should be ok

Comment: Yeah, and now the root component is working, but the URL still changes to root when I navigate to /posrtal/transfers

Comment: What happens if you change ´{ path: '', redirectTo: '/portal/transfers', pathMatch: 'full' },` to `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'transfers', pathMatch: 'full' },`?